# Email with signature Javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook

Why does the following code removes the default Outlook signature?

```
function GetMailToInfo(attachment, body) {
    attachment = attachment ? attachment + lineBreak + lineBreak : lineBreak;
    body += lineBreak + attachment;
    window.location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "?subject=" + self.subject() + "&body=" + body;
}
```

I'm trying to generate an email with the following code but for some reason the email is being opened without the user's default signature.

Any idea on how to solve that?

---

Per @Dmitry Streblechenko's answer:

This is my edited code but the email still opens without the signature:

```
var outlook = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application');
var email = outlook.CreateItem(0);
var insp = email.GetInspector;
email.Subject = self.subject();
email.Display();
email.HTMLBody = body;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are setting the message body. If you don't specify the body, the signature will be added.

There is no way to do what you need with a mailto url. You will need to use the Outlook Object Model.

Create (`new ActiveXObject()`) an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object, use `Application.CreateItem(0)` to create a new message, set the Subject/To/CC/BCC properties, call `MailItem.Display()`. At that point Outlook will add the signature. Now read the `HTMLBody` property, merge it with your own text, then set the HTMLBody property back. You can use the `Body` property (easy to merge the signature with your own data), but then you'll lose the formatting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would you be able to give me an example?

Comment: I can give you an example, but in JS you would only able to use OOM if you are running in IE and your site is trusted (otherwise you won't be able to create COM objects).

Comment: Yes is is only for IE and the site is trusted. (It's a website for internal use of the company), an example would be much appreciated.

Comment: As I mentioned before, after you call Display, read the HTMLBody property(it will contain the signature at this point), merge it with your data, then set the HTMLBody property to the updated value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'read the HTMLBody property', could you explain?

Comment: var MyExistingHTMLBody = email.HTMLBody;